# Notepad++: How to disable text shading in printout

Tags: notepad++

A recent update to Notepad++ added color coding that indicates the state of the lines in the file.
In the picture below, orange signifies lines that have not been saved:

[image: Notepad editor]

When I print the file, it gives those lines an orange background:

[image: Printed document]

What setting would I change to disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this bug with Notepad++ v8.4.6 and had a coloured background (orange and green) like in your picture due to the change process in the printouts or in the PDF.

In the meantime the update Notepad++ v8.4.7 has been released and contains a fix for printing with extra background colors issue due to Change History.

Print to PDF is resulting in:

[image]

Comment: I downloaded the update and all is well now.  Thanks!